# Javascript JQuery https post url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, response

This code works only with Internet explorer 11 but, not with firefox,Chrome, Safari, Opera! In IE I get a response in xml/text but, in the other browsers I got a error message [object Object] ! If i also try to change to an other script source, even IE response return [object Object] !

This cdn will not work at all:

```
<!--<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> Microsoft don't work even with IE 11!-->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  Google not working with no browsers -->
```

How can I get the code to work with all webbrowsers?

This works in IE 11 but, not in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

 console.log($.isXMLDoc(text));//viktig
        $.ajax({
           url: 'https://svenskaspel.se/xternal/xmlegnarader.asp', 
           processData: false,
           type: "POST",  // type should be POST

           data: text, // send the string directly
          // dataType: "text/plain", 
           success: function(response){
             //alert(response);

             var one = response.indexOf("<url>");
             var two = response.indexOf("</url>");  
             var url = response.substring(one+5,two);
             //alert(url);
             window.open(url);


           },
           error: function(response) {
              //alert(response);

           }
        });
```

Comment: This works just fine when I ran it on [https://svenskaspel.se](https://svenskaspel.se): `$.ajax({
    url: 'https://svenskaspel.se/xternal/xmlegnarader.asp', 
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: '1', 
    success: function(response){
        var one = response.indexOf('<url>');
        var two = response.indexOf('</url>');  
        var url = response.substring(one+5,two);
        alert(url);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});`

Comment: Thanks Paul for answering but, I added an alert to response and in firefox I got [object Object] as a response alert! It works in IE11 ?